# How to get days of current week?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

How can I get an array of days of current week?
For example - today is `saturday - 28 july`.
I need array with '28 Saturday', `27 Friday`, `26 Thursday`,`25 Wednesday` ... `22 Sunday`?

[code]   NSCalendar *myCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

```
NSDateComponents *currentComps = [myCalendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:weekDate];
int ff = currentComps.weekOfYear;
NSLog(@"1  %d", ff);

[currentComps setWeekday:1]; // 1: sunday
NSDate *firstDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];
[currentComps setWeekday:7]; // 7: saturday
NSDate *lastDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];

NSLog(@"first - %@ \nlast - %@", firstDayOfTheWeek, lastDayOfTheWeek); [code]
```

I did this, but I have 'firstDayOfWeek' - 2012-07-29 and 'lastDayOfWeek' - 2012-08-04

Comment: just a matter of curiosity: why your current week starts with Friday? And why is it going downward (descending)? Are you from Vladivostok? :))

Comment: Arthur, the nature of this is question indicates that you haven't done any effort to solve this issue yourself. You don't expect for people here to do all the work for you, do you? Please show us what you've tried so far and I'm sure people will be happy to help, including me.

Comment: I agree with @Stavash, this should be fairly simple to figure out simply by searching for this on Google, lots of sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you're looking for - you just need to format the result accordingly:

```
NSDate *weekDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *myCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *currentComps = [myCalendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:weekDate];
int ff = currentComps.weekOfYear;
NSLog(@"1  %d", ff);

[currentComps setWeekday:1]; // 1: sunday
NSDate *firstDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];
[currentComps setWeekday:7]; // 7: saturday
NSDate *lastDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];

NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
myDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd EEEE";
NSString *firstStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *secondStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:lastDayOfTheWeek];

NSLog(@"first - %@ \nlast - %@", firstStr, secondStr);
```